# How do you select the first results from a regex group in Redshift?

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a column in Redshift where I need to parse out an ID from a query string. The below Regex works in all the testers but I can't seem to get Redshift to only return the 1st group which is "75714ae471df63202106404675dasd800097erer1849995367"

What am I missing?

Regex and Redshift query

```
SELECT 

REGEXP_SUBSTR(a.attributes_value, 'GA_ClientID__c\";[^\"]*\([^\"]*)',1) AS ga_clientid

FROM TABLE
```

String Snippet

```
"GA_ClientID__c";s:38:"75714ae471df63202106404675dasd800097erer1849995367";
```

Full string listed below

````
99524";s:9:"FirstName";s:2:"John";s:8:"LastName";s:8:"Doe";s:7:"Company";s:10:"Sample";s:5:"Email";s:20:"xxxxx@gmail.com";s:5:"Phone";s:10:"8888888888";s:7:"Country";s:13:"United States";s:5:"Title";s:8:"Creative";s:5:"State";s:2:"NC";s:13:"Last_Asset__c";s:40:"White Paper: Be a More Strategic Partner";s:16:"Last_Campaign__c";s:18:"70160000000q6TgAAI";s:16:"Referring_URL__c";s:8:"[direct]";s:19:"leadPriorityMarketo";s:2:"P2";s:18:"ProductInterest__c";s:9:"sample";s:14:"landingpageurl";s:359:"https://www.sample.com;mkt_tok=samplesamplesamplesample";s:14:"GA_ClientID__c";s:38:"75714ae471df63202106404675dasd800097erer1849995367";s:13:"Drupal_SID__c";s:36:"e1380c07-0258-47de-aaf8-82d4d8061e1a";s:4:"form";s:4:"1046";} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the opening parenthesis you have to match the closing `"` of the first opening `"` and if you want to match the closing `"` for the second match you could add that as well.

You have to not escape the opening parenthesis `\(` to make it the opening parenthesis of the grouping structure.

Note that you don't have to escape the `\"`

```
GA_ClientID__c";[^"]*"([^"]*)"
                     ^^      ^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6tEd2k/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

`GA_ClientID__c";[^"]*"(.*?)"`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lINoQm/1